# What is this rotating joint called? Where can I find one?

Tags: tools, joints

This round plastic object is inserted horizontally in the wood socket, then rotated and allows tightening the screw to fix together two pieces of my bed.

What is this hardware called?  Can a replacement be purchased independently?

[image]

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic here, but, I believe the hardware you are looking for is called a "cam lock." The round, locking piece is the cam lock nut. It uses a corresponding bolt called, naturally enough, the cam lock bolt.

Comment: @sassafras Nice clean-up

Comment: Could you add an image of the rest of the fixing? I presume the other end of the bolt is conventional, a wide slightly domed head visible on the surface of the piece this rail (?) is joined to but I wanted to check.

Comment: In terms of getting another one off these, I have done numerous searches online in both English and Italian with various search terms and combinations and failed to find it. It may be simplest (and likely cheaper) to just replace with something more common, e.g. a barrel nut and a corresponding bolt of the correct length, plus a washer for under the bolt head. This is more utilitarian but works the same way. You can even do this with a normal hex nut! Ugly, but functional, and even cheaper.... I could buy the parts individually for about €0.40-€1.00 here depending on the length of the bolt.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tracked down where the bed was built and will see if I can get one from them. If not, I will resource to some other solution as @Graphus suggested.

Comment: @Graphus https://www.core77.com/posts/27725/Death-to-Cam-Lock-Nuts-Flatpack-Hardware-That-Will-Hopefully-Become-Obsolete contains a nice picture of both parts of the fixing.  Finding a replacement with "cam lock furniture and nut" was easy. Amazon have them: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Diameter-Locking-Furniture-Fixing-Fixings/dp/B07JC5ZPWX

Comment: For US shoppers: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07BF674TJ/ref=sspa_dk_detail_1?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B07BF674TJ&pd_rd_w=OlziM&pf_rd_p=8a8f3917-7900-4ce8-ad90-adf0d53c0985&pd_rd_wg=PeK9N&pf_rd_r=M66WAFSFGEYM7H631HHK&pd_rd_r=406e2041-c67f-4b97-99e0-4021d77dcf33&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFSVFVNQ0JEOFhaVjEmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA2MTUzODIxTjRBWEFXTzZHUE9NJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA4Mjk1MzFYRExQU1lPMVlLQlUmd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9kZXRhaWwmYWN0aW9uPWNsaWNrUmVkaXJlY3QmZG9Ob3RMb2dDbGljaz10cnVl

Comment: (This is, of course, one of the reasons shopping questions aren't a good fit for this site. Not everyone has the same local availability. Also, because these suppliers come and go, and these links won't be valuable for very long.)

Comment: @MartinBonner, I know what a cam lock is. If I didn't already I could have learned it from the first Comment o_O I had no difficulty at all in finding the type you linked to, but that isn't what's pictured. And if you look closely the bolt is a different kind (not just captured by the rotating cam) so actually this is a completely different fixing.

Comment: Andrea, if you do manage to get a replacement from the bed manufacturer do tell us what they call it if they give it a name (even if it's in Italian)!

Comment: @Graphus You're right.  It *isn't* a cam lock

Answer (score 1):

The hardware you are looking for is called a "cam lock." The round, locking piece is the cam lock nut. It uses a corresponding bolt called, naturally enough, the cam lock bolt.

Answer (score -1):

available at most major big box home centers in the hardware dept. They are usually found in the rack of trays used for the myriad of misc hardware bits and pieces